# How to re-convert the text file produced by pdftotext to pdf again?

Tags: pdf, conversion, poppler

Poppler has the excellent tool `pdftotext` for converting a pdf file to a text file:

```
pdftotext input.pdf output.txt
```

Is there a way to re-convert this text file to pdf?

By conversion, I mean to obtain a pdf file with a similar page content as the original pdf file.

If possible, with the same page numbering as the original (but this is not mandatory). A pdf without page numbering would be also fine.

Exact looking is not important.

**Some potential use-case scenarios:**

1. You have accidentally deleted your pdf file but you have that
   text file from pdftotext.
2. You would like to edit the text file by a text editor and to
   produce an updated version of your pdf file.
3. To produce a pdf file with smaller size.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of options. Theoretically any program that can read plain text and can print can print to a virtual printer that yields a PDF.

But if I were doing it programmatically, I'd probably use [pandoc](https://pandoc.org):

```
pandoc filename.txt -o output.pdf
```

The default uses pdflatex to create the PDF, but if you don't want to install something as heavy as a TeX distribution, there are other backends to use like [weasyprint](https://weasyprint.org/) or [wkhtmltopdf](https://wkhtmltopdf.org/):

```
pandoc --pdf-engine weasyprint filename.txt -o output.pdf
```

But of course the result is never going to preserve the formatting, fonts, etc., of the original, as already pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the program **a2ps** I use a Bash function `a2pdf`:

```
a2pdf () 
{ 
    lowriter --headless --convert-to pdf "$1"
}
```

You surely know that with pdftotext all properties of the PDF like fonts, formatting and links are lost.